# Access both static content and API with Express

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have a Express REST API at `/api` and a frontend that I want to show at `/ui`. I have this:

**api.js**

```
const STATIC_FILES_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'build');
app.use(express.static(STATIC_FILES_PATH));
app.get('/ui', (_, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(STATIC_FILES_PATH, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/api/stuff', (req, res) => {
    //do stuff
});
```

When I navigate to `/api/stuff`, I still see the frontend instead of the API response. No matter the URI, it always show the frontend webpage.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is my project structure:

```
/api
    api.js 
/frontend
    /build
        index.html
```

When I navigate to `/api/stuff`, in my Chrome console, I see a **HTTP 304**! It's redirecting me to the frontend (cached) instead of showing me the JSON result (API response).

Comment: We can't really advise on proper use of `express.static()` without knowing exactly what URLs you want mapped to what files in your file system and we need to see the file hierarchy and know where `__dirname` points in that hierarchy.  Also, I think you want `path.join()`, not `path.resolve()`.  And, it's critical that there is no matching `/api` in your `STATIC_FILES_PATH`.

Comment: Go to the network tab in your browser and see exactly what comes back from your server when you put `/api/stuff` into the URL bar.  If it's something other than what your `app.get('/api/stuff', ...)` handler is sending, then your `express.static()` must be matching `/api/stuff` somehow.  Also, put a `console.log("in api/stuff route")` in your route handler so you can tell if it's even getting called or not.

Comment: Question edited. I'm getting HTTP 304 and redirected to frontend. How can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this using your code as a basis, but it's all working fine. There must be something missing from your question that's causing the issue. You might want to consider creating a [mcve].

Comment: I really don't know why is happening but Express is caching stuff. I found a working solution. I'm going to post it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding this middleware:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Last-Modified', (new Date()).toUTCString());
    next();
});
```

it's working fine. It seems Express is caching stuff. Thanks to all!

Comment: Caching static content is a desirable http feature that improves performance and saves bandwidth.  Why does it cause you a problem?  And, why do you need to disable it?  If you want specific pages to not be cached or have a shorter expiration, you can specify that for just those pages.  Turning off all caching when there are lots of truly static pages is counter-productive.

Comment: Thank for your comment. Problem is that express is showing cached static content even when I want API result, not static content!

Answer (score -1):

change your code with this snippet, it tested and will work correctly.

#### api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

const STATIC_FILES_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build');

app.use(express.static(STATIC_FILES_PATH));

app.get('/ui', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(STATIC_FILES_PATH, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/api/stuff', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({title: 'staff'});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how your code is different from mine?

Comment: Technically there is no different. I check your code and run on my PC, it run correctly and show `/api/staff` and `/ui` in separate page. With Best Regard.

Comment: I'm getting HTTP 304 and being redirected to frontend. Why is that?